# Error MSB6003 The specified task executable "dotnet" could not be run. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform

Tags: angular, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I using Visual studio 2017 latest version===15.8.4
trying to create Angular project from it.

When Create the project i try to run it
the build was unsuccessful and gave me a error such as below:
[Error while running with IIS Express or the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6rRl.png)

=========================================================================

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB6003 
The specified task executable "dotnet" could not be run. The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
NetCoreAngular2_1
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.razor.design\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design.CodeGeneration.targets

## 121

Comment: Any resolution to this. I'm getting the same error.

Comment: try to uninstall all ur dotnet no matter is version 1.0/2.0/2.1/2.2 reinstall only 1 version it works for me